# convert code from arduino to python

Tags: python, arduino, byte

could someone help me to translate this arduino code to python code?

```
#define BUFFLEN 3

byte buffer[] = { 0x05, 0x0D, 0x02, 0xFF, 0x10, 0xAA }

for (byte i=0; i < BUFFLEN; i++) {
    val = analogRead(A0);
    val = constrain(val,0,1023);
    buffer[i*2] = (byte)(i<<2) | highByte(val);
    buffer[i*2+1] = lowByte(val);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which part of the idea are you unsure how to express in Python?

Comment: @6c1 i don't know how to make array of byte of type 0x00, how to address every single index of an array of bytes and how to get high and low of an integer variable (val)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pyserial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) library to capture the data via serial port then process the data using python, in which case the following code would do:

```
import serial
import struct

ser = serial.Serial('COM6',9600) #put the port number and the communication rate


BUFFLEN = 3 #constant

buffer = [ 0x05, 0x0D, 0x02, 0xFF, 0x10, 0xAA ]   #array

i=0  #initialize control variable

def clamp(n, minn, maxn):
    return max(min(maxn, n), minn)

while (i < BUFFLEN):
    val = ser.read()
    val = clamp(val,0,1023)
    buffer[i*2] = (i<<2) or struct.pack('<h', val)
    buffer[i*2+1] = struct.pack('>h', val)
    i+=1    #increment
```

---

But remember to capture and print the data to serial from the arduino IDE